# A step in proving Lie derivatives of vector fields are Lie brackets

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-derivative

Let $X$ be a vector field on a manifold $M$ and $F^t$ its associated flow at time $t$. We define the Lie derivative of $Y$ along $X$ as $$\mathcal{L}_XY:=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{DF^{-t}(Y)-Y}{t}.$$
If we want to put in points, we have at $p\in M$,
$$\mathcal{L}_XY|_p:=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{DF^{-t}(Y|_{F^t(p)})-Y|_p}{t}.$$
I want to show the identity $\mathcal{L}_X Y=[X,Y]$, and in some point along the proof, it seems that I need to show the identity
$$(*)\lim_{t\to 0}DF^t(\mathcal{L}_XY)=\mathcal{L}_XY$$
in order to show the identity
$$\mathcal{L}_X Y=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{Y-DF^t(Y)}{t}.$$
Is $(*)$ correct, and if so, how do I show it?

Comment: Your notation is weird, you write it as a composition when really it's the pullback ofnthe vector field. Anyway, for any vector field $Z$, we have by definition $((F^t)^*Z)_p= (D(F^{-t}))[Z_{F^t(p)}]$. If you really want, write out the expression on the right in terms of a chart around the point $p$. You'll see that because $(t, p) \mapsto F^t(p)$ is smooth, and since $F^0(p)=p$, the limit on the right is just $Z_p$.

Comment: For the notation remark you referring to $DF^{-t}(Y)$? I wrote the same as you did, but just didn't put in points and or parentheses for clarity. Either way, I'm just following Petersen's notation. Also, are you claiming my (*) formula holds for any vector field $Z$ and for any smooth 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $F^t$?

Comment: Any smooth 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms with $F^0$ being the identity, yes.

Comment: Regarding notation, you're writing $DF^{-t}(Y)$, which looks like the composition $(DF^{-t})\circ Y$ (which isn't even a vector field), when really you mean the pullback $(F^t)^*Y=(DF^{-t})\circ Y\circ F^t$. These two are obviously different maps.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll think about this. On the notation, I agree that we both mean pullback of the vector field $Y$. But what does $Y\circ F^t$ mean? $Y$ here is a vector field. In my notation, $DF^{-t}$ denotes the differential of the map $F^{-t}$, and the $(Y)$ denotes evaluation on the vector field $Y$. The drawback here is that I'm suppressing points.

Comment: A vector field is a smooth map $Y:M\to TM$ (such that $\pi_{TM}\circ Y=\text{id}_{M}$). We also have a smooth map $F^t:M\to M$. So, we just compose them $Y\circ F^t$ in the usual sense. After all this is what you mean when you wrote everything with the points included $DF^{-t}(Y|_{F^t(p)})$. The fact that you're evaluating $Y$ at $F^t(p)$ means we're talking about the composition $Y\circ F^t$. That's why I said $DF^{-t}(Y)$ alone is bad notation. It should be $DF^{-t}\circ Y\circ F^t$ (or $DF^{-t}(Y|_{F^t(\cdot)})$ to indicate correctly where the point of evaluation goes).